# Changing ScrollView (Horizontal/Vertical) in layout and layout-land

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout-land folder and copied my activity_main.xml file so that I can re-position some views to make it more optimised for landscape viewing. Everything is fine until I change my `ScrollView`; portrait uses vertical and landscape uses horizontal. My app will then crash as it cannot cast ScrollView into HorizontalScrollView and vice versa.

```
android.widget.ScrollView cannot be cast to android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
```

Unfortunately both of the orientations cannot use the same `HorizontalScrollView` or `VerticalScrollView` as it will become messed up and not possible to use the scrolling feature as intended.

I have looked on stackoverflow and google but could not find anything relevant probably due to the wording of the problem. What would be the best solution? Would I have to create the `ScrollView` within Java code and not via xml?

EDIT - requested code:
Okay so my MainActivity onCreate() has

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
```

In my layout\activity_main.xml I am using

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:visibility="visible">
....
</ScrollView>
```

In land\activity_main.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:visibility="visible">
....
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky I don't think code sample is not neccesery as all I'm doing is specifying a ScrollView in the xml file and then casting/initializing it in Java code. My problem is that I can either set the ScrollView to Horizontal or Vertical. When I turn the phone to other orientation it will crash as it is using the other .xml which has initialized that ScrollView as e.g. Horizontal and then it tries casting to Vertical which then results in a crash.

Comment: Post `Activity`/`Fragment` code. What you want to do with `ScrollView`/`HorizontalScrollView`? Parent class of `ScrollView`/`HorizontalScrollView` is `android.widget.FrameLayout` try to cast...

Comment: Please post your code concerning onCreate(), we can't help you without some code... I wanted to see if you initialized ScrollView in your code or not.

Comment: @dieter_h updated my post with code. I want the ScrollView to be Vertical (ScrollView) when in portrait and Horizontal (HorizontalScrollView) when in landscape mode. I assume I cannot do this via xml.

Comment: I am having the same problem, however, I am not accessing the ScrollViews in Java code at all, but am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any **ScrollView** specific functions, you can just declare it a **View**.  If you do, you need to treat them separately because they are different classes:

```
if (isLandscape())
    mHorizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
else
    mScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
```

Where isLandscape() is:

```
private boolean isLandscape() {
    return getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
}
```

Then whenever you want to use your scrollview, check orientation and use the right one.  Alternatively, you can use just one member *mScrollView* as just a View, and cast to **HorizontalScrollView** or **ScrollView** when you actually call the method you need.

Comment: Here is my implementation www.gyazo.com/56d3660efa17dd4e143657d139a3ef89 but as before as soon as the screen is rotated the app crashes horribly.  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.HorizontalScrollView$SavedState Is it something I'm doing wrong or to put it simply; the idea cannot be achieved in a way I want it to function?

Comment: Try changing the ID of the horizontal scroll view in your layout file to something else, like horizontalScrollView.  It looks like it's attempting to save the scroll position for you but since it's a different class it crashes when attempting to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
FrameLayout scrollView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work: android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState cannot be cast to android.widget.HorizontalScrollView$SavedState